# No free space in / directory

Tags: partitioning

I have 10 GB for the root and 30 GB for the home folder.
Home folder is 7 GB used up and it shows the root folder's space is 100% in use, of which 70% usage is home folder.

I am unable to install any new software cause of the disk space error.
Trying to delete anything I installed, clearing the trash, clears out the space from the home folder but doesn't effect the other one.

Comment: If you've got `/home` as a separate partition, as you're suggesting it won't take up the space from `/`. Can you Edit your question with  the output of `sudo du -hs /*`, `sudo df -h`

Comment: Post the result of `df -H` into your question. And you better not have / and /home as different partition because I would assume you understand what that means. Deleting stuff from /home frees space from /home but you assume this affects / how exactly? And please explain what you put on / that made it fill up 10Gb. For a plain desktop 10Gb is more than enough.

Comment: also edit into the question results of `du -a /var | sort -n -r | head -n 10`. This will show the 10 largest dirs and files. Maybe you put personal data into / without realizing ;)

Comment: `clearing the trash, clears out the space from the home folder but doesn't effect the other one.`  Then it is likely that you do have /home on a different partition rather than as part of /.  Which means something else is taking up space on /.  The du commands from other will show the still existing largest files, which may help. If those do not then please try the following:

Comment: 0) Reboot. If disk space mysteriously drops and you might have open (and in use) but already deleted files. Not uncommon with logfiles.
1) Reboot and put the output of mount (or /etc/fstab)  in your post.
2) Clean /tmp (assuming it is a real filesystem and not a ramdisk).

Comment: Last comment: (Sorry for the semi abuse of comments) What is the precise error. Does it mention inodes?

Answer (score 2):

just check with

```
du -hsx /* | sort -rh | head -10
```

you folder sizes of your system. Maybe there are some big files you doesn't need.

Alterative you can enlarge you root partition.